# Get sum of unique trades and the sum of the associated payments in SQL one to many relatioship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `trades` and `payments` whereas single trade may have  0...* (none or many) payments.

I want to get the sum of all trade amounts and the sum of all associated payment amounts, for a trade belonging to a specific client/user.

Here is the query that gives the result of all trades and payments, BUT one of trade_amount is duplicated (the one for trade_id = 3) because there are two payments made against that trade:

```
SELECT t.id          AS trade_id,
       t.sell_amount AS trade_amount,
       p.id          AS pay_id,
       p.trade_id    AS pay_trade_id,
       p.amount      AS pay_amount
  FROM trades AS t
  JOIN payments AS p
    ON p.trade_id = t.id
 WHERE t.client_id = 88
```

and here is the result:
trade_id    trade_amount    pay_id  pay_trade_id    pay_amount

```
trade_id | trade_amount | pay_id | pay_trade_id | pay_amount
1        | 10           | 1      | 1            | 10
2        | 20           | 2      | 2            | 20
3        | 30           | 3      | 3            | 10
3        | 30           | 4      | 3            | 10
```

I can't obtain the correct SUM of the **trade_amount**s because it would add the amount of `trade_id = 3` twice, hence the sum would be **90** ❌. That is not what I want! The desired result would be the sum of all DISTINCT trades, hence SUM of all distinct trade amounts 10+20+30 = 60✅

As for the payments, the sum is pretty straightforward since there aren't any repetitions/duplicates of payments, hence SUM(pay_amount) would yield to correct result 10+20+10+10=50✅

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/043d69/3) to play with.

I would like to get a result that would yield desired sums:

trade_amount_sum = **60** (but I get 90)

pay_amount_sum   = 50     (and I get 50 and that is correct)

Comment: You could aggregate the trade_amount in a CTE. I recommend showing your desired output too. But format text and remove pictures is best.

Comment: Posting images of technical information like sample data or results, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCoehoorn
Corrections made and
I will keep that in mind for future posts

Answer (score 0):

When you JOIN two tables, you get all combinations of rows matching the ON conditions.  When table `a` has one row that matches multiple rows in table `b` you'll get multiple copies of the data from tables `a` in your results. That leads to a combinatorial explosion. No fun. Baffling.

So you need to use subqueries that generate only one possible combination of rows.

The aggregating subquery to get exactly one row per `trades.id` is this.

```
       SELECT id, client_id, 
              SUM(sell_amount) AS sell_amount
         FROM trades
        GROUP BY id, client_id
```

Then join it to your other table instead of your detail `trades` table.

```sql
SELECT t.id          AS trade_id,
       t.sell_amount AS trade_amount,
       p.id          AS pay_id,
       p.trade_id    AS pay_trade_id,
       p.amount      AS pay_amount
  FROM (  SELECT  id, 
                  client_id,
                  SUM(sell_amount) AS sell_amount
             FROM trades
            GROUP BY id, client_id
       ) AS t
  JOIN payments AS p
    ON p.trade_id = t.id
 WHERE t.client_id = 88
```

When generating these sorts of reports, you need to aggregate your detail tables *separately* to get a single row per report row. Otherwise you'll get the combinatorial explosion ... multiples of the correct COUNT and SUM values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm afraid I haven't made my point clear enough though.
Probably because my English is not very good.
I updated the original post and provided a fiddle playground.
I hope that would make my question more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum up only distinct trade amounts like this:

```
  SELECT 
       SUM(DISTINCT(t.sell_amount)) AS trade_amount_sum,
       SUM(p.amount)      AS pay_amount_sum
  FROM trades AS t
  JOIN payments AS p
    ON p.trade_id = t.id
 WHERE t.client_id = 88;
```